# I am getting this error publishing an ASP.Net web project: "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am working two ASP.Net Web apps. After some edits and updates I wanted to publish one and deploy for testing using own local host PC as the server. Previously publishing it worked in VS 2022. But after I installed IIS and added it as an application I could not publish it from Visual Studio. I tried removing the app. from IIS and manually setting the publish path. I also uninstalled IIS and restarted the PC.

The Output error I get is:

The item metadata "%(FullPath)" cannot be applied to the path "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp...

Anyone know of a way to correct this?

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, you can try to move the project to the root of folder, or you can [enable the Win32 long paths policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41687101/13336642) to fix the issue. Besides, here's another reference you can refer to: [Resource file name too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19387464/resource-file-name-too-long).

Comment: Thanks. The project is in a repo with a short path. I'm not sure why its trying to publish it in the temporary folder, but I will enable long paths and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:
I was able to fix the problem by deleting
'FolderProfile.pubxml' and 'FolderProfile.pubxml.user' in the Project \PublishProfiles sub-folder.

I also deleted the 'website.publishProj' file from the main project folder.

This cleared the publish settings and fixed the problem.